# Several graph theory proofs

Tags: graph-theory

1. Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $|V|=n$. Prove that $G$ is connected if $d(v)\geq \frac{n-1}{2}$ for all $v\in V$.
2. Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $|V|=n$ and $|E|=m$. Prove that $\min\limits_{u\in V} d(u) \leq 2\dfrac{m}{n}\leq \max\limits_{v\in V}d(v)$.

---

My attempts:

1. $|E|\leq n(n-1)$ since every node can have at most $n-1$ edges, and there are $n$        nodes in total. Hence making use of the formula $\sum\limits_{v\in V}d(v)=2|E|$, we obtain $\sum\limits_{v\in V}d(v)\leq 2n(n-1)$. I don't know how to proceed from here.
2. All I can come up with is that $\max\limits_{v\in V}d(v)=n-1$. I don't think this helps me though.

---

Could anyone please provide any additional hints to these problems? Thank you in advance

Comment: 1. You might find hints in the following question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728795/prove-thoroughly-if-the-degree-of-all-vertices-is-greater-or-equal-to-fracv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Actually, $|E|\leq n(n-1)/2$; you are counting each edge twice, when it goes from a node, and when it goes to a node. Take two arbitrary nodes $x,y$. If they are not connected, then there is not an edge between them, so all the outgoing edges from $x$ must go to at least $(n-1)/2$ nodes other than $x$. Similarly all the outgoing edges from $y$ must go to at least $(n-1)/2$ nodes, all distinct from both $x$ and the neighbors of $x$, or otherwise $G$ would be connected. But wait, how many nodes have we used already...?
2. Use the formula $\sum_v d(v)=2m$. Suppose $\min_v d(v)\leq 2m/n$ were false, then $d(v)>2m/n$ for all $v$. Insert into the formula. Do the same thing for the inequality $2m/n\leq \max_v d(v)$.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your help, I very much appreciate it. For $1$, do you mean that we have used $\frac{n-1}{2}+\frac{n-1}{2} = n-1$ nodes so far, and hence if you add $x$ and $y$ we have used $n+1$ nodes which is one too many $\rightarrow$ contradiction? For $2$, I am not entirely sure what you mean. How can you prove a formula by using an argument which involves proving by contradiction? Contradiction does not seem like a way in which you can come up with a formula if it would not have been given.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. The formula is given, so there's no problem here. Often how you come up with a statement is different from the way how you prove it.

Comment: Thanks :). So for $2$, do you mean that because $d(v)$> $2 \dfrac{m}{n} \quad \forall v$, $\min\limits_{v\in V}d(v)$>$2\dfrac{m}{n}$ and $\max\limits_{v\in V}d(v)$>$ 2\dfrac{m}{n}$ and that from the second inequality then follows the opposite (so both the minimum and maximum are strictly larger than...) that we have a contradiction?

Comment: You haven't used the formula $\sum_v d(v)=2m$. Also you need to use strict inequalities $<,>$.

Comment: I was just in the process of editing the inequalities ;). How would you use that formula then? And don't the two opposite strict inequalities already lead to a contradiction?

Comment: Do each case separately. First prove that $\min_v d(v)\leq 2m/n$ can't be true, because you will get a contradiction against the formula $\sum_v d(v)=2m$. You will not use anything about the maximum to do this. The proof for the other case will be similar, but I recommend you to sit down and do it with as much detail as in the first case.

Comment: Am I right to assume that you mean that I should prove $d(v)$ >$2m/n$ can't be true (as you stated in your original answer)? And could you please show me how I would go about doing this, as I cannot seem to work it out still. Thank you.

Comment: $d(v)>2m/n\implies \sum_v d(v)>\sum_v 2m/n=n2m/n=2m$, which contradicts $\sum_vd(v)=2m$.

Comment: Ah, I see :-). Thanks a lot for your help. I did not think of taking the summation on both sides of the inequality. So for the maximum, if I am right it follows that $d(v)$ < $2m/n\quad \forall v$, hence $\sum_vd(v)$ < $\sum_v2m/n=2m$, which again contradicts $\sum_vd(v)=2m$?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but upon rereading your answer to question 1, I have one more thing that I am not entirely sure about. Why is it true that all the outgoing edges from x must go to \emph{at least} $(n−1)/2$ nodes? Should it not be \emph{at most} $(n−1)/2$ (I get that the proof does then not make sense any more but I just cannot seem to grasp why your statement is true)?

Comment: If the degree of a node is $d(v)$, then it is adjacent to exactly $d(v)$ nodes, and $d(v)\geq (n-1)/2$.

Comment: Hahaha pffff, how stupid, I forgot that this was given in the question :O. Thanks again.