# Prove that the degrees lie in a range

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $|V|=n$ and $|E|=m$ prove that
$$
\min_{u\in V} \{d(u)\}\leq 2\frac{m}{n}\leq \max_{v\in V} \{ d(v)\} 
$$
now my first intuition is to assume that $\min\limits_{u\in V} \{d(u)\} =0$ holds because it is not a connected graph. And my second assumption is to use $\max\limits_{v\in V} \{ d(v)\} =n -1$ (connected to everything, except it self) , and from another exercise we got

> $$
> d(v)\geq \frac{n-1}{2}
> $$

which could be interpreted as
$$
n-1\leq 2d(v)
$$
which would help in getting the right side, the only thing baffling me at the moment is the $\frac{m}{n}$ part, any intuition on this?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401942/several-graph-theory-proofs

Comment: woops, search didnt give it. Thanks!

Comment: How do people invent so many weird ways of failing to understand TeX?  I couldn't in a million years think of all this stuff.  I changed \underset{u\in V}{min} to \min_{u\in V} and several similar things.  In a "displayed" setting, the latter looks like this: $\displaystyle\min_{u\in V}$.  The former, on the other hand, looks like this: $\underset{u\in V}{min}$.  Not only is it improperly in italics, but it lacks proper spacing in expressions like $\displaystyle a\min_{u\in V}b$, thus: $a\underset{u\in V}{min}b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Mostly me not knowing every trick in the book :) I'll keep it in mind. jeezh. im glad I even know a bit of TeX

Comment: @WiseStrawberry One should learn \underset *way* after \min

Comment: I just look up whatever I need and didnt know \min was available. I learn when I need it, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about we just summarize all the degrees? We know:

$$\min_{v \in V} d(v) \le d(u) \le \max_{v \in V} d(v).$$

Applying this to all elements in the sum $2m = \sum_{u \in V} d(u)$, we get that

$$n \min_{v \in V} d(v) \le \sum_{u \in V} d(u) \le n\max_{v \in V} d(v),$$

so

$$\min_{v \in V} d(v) \le \frac{2m}{n} \le \max_{v \in V} d(v).$$

Comment: didnt even think of using summations! Thanks a lot. Not using $$\min_{v \in V} d(v) \le d(u) \le \max_{v \in V} d(v).$$  was just silly of me.